# Target [Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory] is not instantiable

Tags: laravel, lumen, laravel-socialite, lumen-5.2

I am using laravel lumen 5.2.

Target [Laravel\Socialite\Contracts\Factory] is not instantiable.

I came across this error when trying to get Laravel to login with Twitter using the Socialite package.

Work already done:

A) In config\app.php
1. Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class
2. 'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class

I followed this :
http://goodheads.io/2015/08/24/using-twitter-authentication-for-login-in-laravel-5/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What helped me is writing

```
use Socialite;
```

in the controller (just the alias, not the full path). And then running

```
php artisan config:clear
```

in the terminal.

Answer (score 12):

You would need to add the following in `config/app.php`

In providers add this

```
Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class
```

In aliases add this

```
'Socialite' => Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite::class
```

Comment: That was my problem. Thanks.

Comment: lumen doesn't have `config/app.php`

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was to add    `$app->register( \Laravel\Socialite\SocialiteServiceProvider::class);`  to `app.php` in the bootstrap folder, using `Lumen 5.6`.